# Is there any way to switch your point character after character selection but before the match?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-3

In MVC2, if you held either of the assist buttons going into the match, that character would come out first, in place of the character you chose first.  If you held both assist buttons, the 2nd and 3rd characters would switch positions.

Is there any analogue to this functionality in the new 3rd installment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can switch before battle: just press and hold <kbd>L1</kbd> or <kbd>R1</kbd> during the "loading screen".

Comment: That's where I was getting it wrong.  I thought it might be possible after the loading screen but during the characters pre-battle taunts.

Comment: @Strix Glad I could help :)

Comment: Was wondering if you could do this!  Thanks for the helpful answer.